# How to say "this?" interjection in chinese?

Tags: translation, grammar, vocabulary

For example of a case:

(I was in home walking holding a jar of chocolate candy, I was gonna go to upstairs)
Mom: (She saw me and she called me from behind) "Where did you buy that?"
Me: (I was a bit startled, I turned back and showing up the jar) **What?! This?** <== I need chinese translation of the bold text.

How about **"什么？！这个？”** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, 什么？ 这个？ is correct.

You could also say something like:

你说的是这个？ (are you talking about this?) to clarify that what they're talking about is in fact the candy.

Comment: Would you need `吗` after `这个`, i.e. `这个吗`?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: erm, could you elaborate a little please? :P

Comment: In this case it's honestly your choice

Comment: @Cocowalla Since this is a colloquial conversation, you can add any modal particles as you like, but none of them is grammatically required. You can say 这个吗, 这个呀, 这个啊, etc. depending on the specific situation and your delivery. If you're not yet proficient in spoken Chinese, adding 吗 is probably the safest choice which has the least chance of being misunderstood.